# ¿Se escribe "r" simple para el sonido "rr" tras otras consonantes aparte de "l", "n" y "s"?

Tags: ortografía, letras

Es una regla conocida que se escribe "r" simple para el sonido "rr" cuando esta aparece tras las consonantes que forman la palabra *lunes*. Pero ¿es posible que se deba escribir también "r" simple tras otras consonantes?

Comment: Interesante la regla nemotécnica con la palabra lunes :)

Comment: @MauricioMartinez de las que nunca se olvidan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sí, [existe otra regla](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=r) que amplía esta. Básicamente dice que se escribe "r" simple si esta no forma sílaba con la anterior consonante. Así, se dan los siguientes casos:

- Palabras que empiezan por "r" tras los sufijos *ab-*, *sub-* y *post-*: *[abrogar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0BXkZf5)*, *[subrayar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YYmdQFQ)*, *[postromántico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Toiazz5)*. En este caso, por ejemplo, la primera "r" de *abrogar* no se pronuncia igual que la de *abrevar*, por ser la primera palabra un compuesto con el prefijo *ab-* más una palabra cuyo sonido empieza por "rr" y que se mantiene en el compuesto.
- El caso particular del gentilicio *[ciudadrealeño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9NfKnKn)*. Al ser un compuesto de dos palabras, estas mantienen su pronunciación en la palabra compuesta, por lo que la "r" de "realeño" no se pronuncia igual que la primera de *drenar*.