# ¿Por qué «ronronear» no se escribe con doble ere?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación

La segunda ere de *ronronear* obviamente es una ere vibrante: /ronroneˈaɾ/, no /ronɾoneˈaɾ/. (Se puede escuchar [aquí](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=ronronear).) A pesar de eso, se escribe con una sola ere.

¿Por qué es así?

Comment: Además de la respuesta que te han dado, puedes consultar más casos en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23562/12637).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La regla ortográfica dice que después de *l, n, s* se escribe una sola "r" aunque se pronuncie "rr":

- alrededor
- enredar
- Israel

[Referencia](https://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/reglas-ortograficas-de-la-r-rr-d-z-x-y-la-s/#:%7E:text=Aunque%20el%20sonido%20sea%20fuerte,%3A%20vicerrector%2C%20contrarr%C3%A9plica%2C%20etc.)

Comment: ¿‘lr’ ‘nr’ ‘sr’ siempre se pronuncian /lr/ /nr/ /sr/?

Comment: Siempre se pronuncian /lrr/ /nrr/ /srr/